# why my xampp server time is 4 hours lower than local pc time?

Tags: php, xampp

I am working on a php project. I want to show the local pc time. But it shows 4 hours slower than my pc time. I am in Asia/Dhaka region. And I use this code to get the time

```
$punchout_time=date("H:i");
```

Note: I have already change the time zone in php.ini. But it does not work
Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Did you restart your XAMPP after changing the timezone in php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

> Note: I have already change the time zone in php.ini

Did You restarted Apache?